# How to find the App running in the foreground using private API in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Is there a way to know which App is running in the foreground while your App is in the background? Either using public or private API, I am just doing the R&D so I am ok to use the private API as well.

Comment: Seeking recommendations for external api (link) is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think no.

iOS should not provide a possibility to detect other applications for security reasons.

Otherwise, this is a vulnerability in iOS :)